# Talend ESB convert xml to json in route

Tags: apache-camel, esb, talend, eip

Someone knows how to convert xml to json and json to xml in Talend ESB route?
When I receive rest message in Job I can configure "consume" and "produce", but how to do this in Route. I need to do some mediation on rest message, so I have to use Route (Content Based Routing), becasue EIP is in Route.

Example:

```
RestEndpoint_IN->MessageRouter->ConvertXmlToJson->RestEndpoint_Out.
```

In response I need:

```
RestEndpoint_Out->ConvertJsonToXml->RestEndpoint_IN
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the xmljson camel component to do this.

### Steps:

- Verify that you have the XOM library in your talend lib folder. (Talend ESB\Runtime_ESBSE\lib). 
  It seems to be missing in the current talend installation, you can get it from here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xom/xom/1.2.5 (restart talend if you had to copy it)
- In your route add a cConfig widget if you dont already have one. In Basic Settings->dependencies add the xom library. Now you are ready to just use the component; it is quite straight forward from here.
- Add a cMessagingEndpoint widget.

  - In the URI use: "dataformat:xmljson:unmarshal?" for going from json to xml.   If you need to go from xml to json use "dataformat:xmljson:marshal?" .
  - In the Advanced Settings tab select xmljson
- You can rename your widget to something like "Convert body to XML".

### Explanation:

Talend forums are not very helpful. They simply mention the xmljson component, but if you dont have a good grasp of camel, it is very confusing.
The cMessagingEndpoint widget simply translates to a ".to()" method in the java dsl. The camel components listed here: http://camel.apache.org/components.html support URI identifiers. As you can see we used the DataFormat URI form which allow to use the camel core marshal and unmarshal methods to convert between formats. The easiest way to convert xml to json is to use camel-xmljson (http://camel.apache.org/xmljson.html), but it requires 2 jars and one of them (XOM) is missing in the current talend installation, thats why we need to add the dependency using the cConfig widget.

- http://camel.apache.org/data-format.html
- http://camel.apache.org/components.html
- http://camel.apache.org/dataformat-component.html
- http://camel.apache.org/xmljson.html
- https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioforESBUserGuide60EN/4.3.4+How+to+use+Camel+components+in+a+Route

Answer (score 1):

There are java functions that will do the job for you, juste write your code in a bean and add it in your route (or a cProcessor that will call it), you juste have to get the message content with "exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class)", transform it, then set the result with "exchange.getIn().setBody()"